# Is terahertz radiation new?

Tags: radiation

Regarding the future applications of terahertz technology, I thought we already knew the entire electromagnetic spectrum. In fact we do not, terahertz lies between microwaves and infrared radiation. The future applications of this is astonishing. For example, faster communications and next generation scanning and imaging technologies. The TSA will pretty much be out of a job, because T-Ray(terahertz) scanners will automatically detect chemical weapons and bombs. I know this because they leave a trace on the terahertz spectrum. The downside with communications is terahertz is absorbed easily by the Earth's atmosphere, so the communications cannot be too high in the sky. What I am asking is, are there any other frequencies on the electromagnetic spectrum we might discover? I was taught in school, that there are radio waves, microwaves, infrared, visible, ultra violent, x-rays, and gamma rays. Now the books have to be rewritten because of the existence of terahertz or t-rays. Remember it lies right between microwaves and infrared radiation. Another question is what about sound? So far there is infra sound, sound, and ultrasound. Do you think in the future we will discover other types of sound? Sorry for the length of my question, as you can see I know a lot about science and technology.

Comment: We did know of all the spectrum ever since Maxwell's equations were discovered. But only relatively recently have we become able to generate terahertz radiation efficiently, that's why only now talks are about its applications.

Comment: "Fascinating, captain: a new form of energy!"  <-- As all other responses indicate,  certainly not.

Comment: I recently counted my book collection and learned that I own 5,743 books.  I do not recall ever having 5,743 of anything in the past.  Is the number 5,743 new?

Answer (score 1):

It is just a matter of semantics, what one calls the slices of the spectra The spectra exist and were known since the [nineteenth century.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_spectrum) If one is able to concentrate on a particular scale and christens it with a new name, there is no problem.

[image: em spectrum]

> A diagram of the electromagnetic spectrum, showing various properties across the range of frequencies and wavelengths

The classification depended on the type of detection.

Particularly for sound, which is what the ear hears, and the other two , ultra , which means over and  infra  below, are just what the ear hears and above or below.

Comment: THz radiation is not new. What is new: We learn to create more sources and detectors to handle (more or less efficiently) THz radiation. The technology is a little bit different from microwave/infrared device and to address this specificity you use the term "THz"-technology.

Answer (score 1):

Terahertz waves are not new, but sources and detectors become available at better price every year.  That's why many laboratories ([like lt3](https://lt3.fr)) around the world focus on this activity with many applications. We can mention millimeter wave technologies coming from microwave that become cheaper due to it's massive use for automotive radars and the next 5G.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Jagadish Bose was generating and detecting millimeter waves before 1900!

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagadish_Chandra_Bose

He pioneered some amazing technology for studying mmw polarization.  He was the first I think to use a point contact semi-conductor (naturally occurring galena) for detection (cat's whiskers).  A true pioneer in RF technology.